# Managed Package Providers No longer able to access Debug Logs

Tags: managed-package, debugging

I just wanted to double check because we are having trouble seeing debug logs for our extension packages in subscriber orgs. The main package which started it all works fine.

I am being told by SF support that providers are no longer able to see debug logs unless they contact support and have the namespace added to the subscriber org. If this is true it is going to be a huge problem.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/apex_debugging_sub_org.htm

> This is Ana on behalf of Marian. As I understand, you are having
>   issues performing debug of your package via LMA when you log in to the
>   subscriber org. The document that you provided is correct. However,
>   you can perform this once the "Managed namespaces to log in Apex Debug
>   Log" is enabled under the subscriber org.
>
> Debugging for Managed Packages is actually not enabled by default. Our
>   Tier 3 can enable this on your subscriber org if you will be
>   performing troubleshooting and this is only temporary. Since it might
>   cause performance issues when this is enabled permanently

Anyone else seeing this behavior? Can anyone confirm that what support is telling me vs what we "know" or at least used to know to be correct is now no longer possible?

**UPDATE**

I had to close the case because they kept insisting that I had to enable the namespace in the client org. They wanted a client's org ID so they could do it and test despite the fact that it had nothing to do with the question.

What I did find is that the listing had a depreciated Package association. So it appears that in order to see debug logs when accessing subscriber instances you must not only have the dev org connected via the LMA but additionally must have an app exchange listing and it must be linked to a valid package.

Without the listing debug logs did not work, once a listing was created the debug logs could be seen as expected

**UPDATE 2/2/2017**

Batch logs are not able to be seen. In order to see batch logs you have to call the execute method directly passing in NULL for the batchableContext.....

Comment: It appear that you have 2 packages main package and extension package? is that correct?

Comment: 1 Main package and several extension packages yes. Debug used to work just fine until we added 3 other extension packages. They are connected appropriately as far as I can tell yet for the new extensions we cannot see logs. (Other that the query executions and Entering managed package parts. Logs always say requested by xxxxx which is main package). Going to do a test and see if we can see the original extension package logs today.

Comment: Just checked one of our original extension packages and debug logs are working fine. Its only the new extension packages that are an issue. Licenses show in the LMA so they are connected properly AFAIK. I really hope they did not nerf this ability for new packages....

Comment: As they are different packages they must be having different namespace. May be that is why its causing the issue.

Comment: Were the extension packages put through security review? Honestly, the response from Support sounds like BS and I hope this got sorted years ago!